# What is best pattern for angular js: MVVM or MVC?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I am new in angular js. I want to know difference between MVVM and MVC framework and which one is best for AngularJS.

I know about MVC and MVVM pattern but I can not find which one is best and why?

Thanks,
Hitesh

Comment: Angular is a MVC architecture.... well at least up to 2 is. But you do what ever makes sense in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVVM, the UI (the View), faces the user and takes user input directly. Within the View, Commands within the ViewModel (which is the DataContext of the View) are triggered by this activity. Control flows to the ViewModel which interprets what the View has sent it and prepares its Models. After control flows back to the View it updates itself according to changes in the Models. If a new View is required, the ViewModel communicates this with the NavigationService (or whatever method of navigation your application uses), which is the purview of the Window or Frame--UI components. You can see that the ViewModel isn't first and last to act; the View plays a much greater role than in MVC.

The architecture of WPF/Silverlight is the reason why things are done this way. The command, binding and navigation infrastructures can't be controlled/replaced by the Controller; they are tightly integrated with the UI. So the Controller must sit below the View and take a more passive role.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is MV*(MV what ever) either it can be MVC or MVVC.

- Model : Data you want to update.
- View : HMLT/Template.
- Controller : function which maintains application data and behavior.

1. Example for MVC is binding data to view using Interpolation {{}}.
   You can update view(html) using controller.
2. Example for MVVC is two way data binding using ngModel.
   If you bind a ngModel to input tag.
   Value changed in input filed is updated in controller.
   Value changed in controller is updated in input field.